# If x and y are column vectors, what is $y - \hat{\beta}^T x$?

Tags: least-squares, matrix

We are predicting the outcome y for a new data point x (a column vector). If we had observed y, what is $y - \hat{\beta}^T x$ typically known as?

I thought $y - \hat{\beta} x$ was the residuals, but with $\hat{\beta}^T$, I'm not sure if it is something else.

Comment: This question is thin. Can you add detail? What transformation?

Comment: Added the rest of the question

Comment: What is the transpose of a real number, say 3?

Comment: The same number?

Answer (score 0):

In univariate and multivariate regression, $X$ (or more precisely $\mathbf{X}$) can be a *design* matrix or model matrix. The number of columns of $X$ is $p$ and the rows are $n$. $X$ is not a vector. The first column is a sequence of constants, usually 1, representing the intercept term. So a univariate regression would have $p=2$ and require a design matrix to estimate the model parameters: a slope and an intercept. The resulting *vector* of parameters $\beta$ is also a $p \times 1$ matrix. The transpose (superscript-T) conforms the parameter vector to multiply the design matrix and give the fitted values as an $n \times 1$ matrix of the same dimension as $Y$. $Y-\hat{\beta}^TX$ is the residuals vector. The minus (-) operator transmutes two matrices, so that $Y-\hat{\beta}^T X$ is calculated by differencing each element of the two matrices element-wise.